# Hyperledger Composer Ping gives REQUEST_TIMEOUT

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am working on composer v0.16. I am trying to add 2 new nodes to an existing 2 node blockchain network. Everything works fine on the first 2 nodes. On the new nodes, when I try to ping the network with the peer Admin card or try to interact with the network using the card, the operation waits for a long time and then gives a "Error: Error trying invoke business network. Error: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT" error.

I have checked the composer version is same on all 4 nodes. The state of the identity is "Bound" not "Active". Anything else that can be done to check version mismatch. What else can be checked?

Comment: More information needed - are the new 'nodes' Peers in the same organisation, or a new organisation?  Have the new Peers been joined to the channel? What other errors are you seeing?  What do the logs of the docker containers for the working and non-working peers show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was trying to find the Orderer using the Orderer alias name in the connection.json and failing. Hence the timeout. Replacing the Orderer alias with the actual hostname resolved the issue.